# rsync cron job for backup not working

Tags: backup, macos, rsync, cron

I'm trying to run a backup from one HDD to another at 10pm everynight on a Mac Pro. I have tested the `rsync` and it backups just fine outside of the `cron` table. Here is what I have and it's not running

`* 20 * * * rsync -av /Volumes/HDD1/* /Volumes/HDDbackup/`

This is on a Mac Pro that doesn't get turned off nightly

Comment: What are your sleep settings?

Comment: Computer is set to never and display is set to 1 hour.

Comment: OK, it's not a sleep issue. My best guess is the hard drives are not mounted when cron runs.

Comment: Further research has revealed that the user does manually lock their PC at the end of the day. However, the system is still not set to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Use `00 22 * * * rsync -av /Volumes/HDD1/* /Volumes/HDDbackup/` (instead of 20 - which is 8 pm!) and it will run - set up with the proper user and proper disk permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `/Volumes/HDD1` and `/Volumes/HDDbackup` are internal drives then your crontab should be:

```
00 22 * * * rsync -av /Volumes/HDD1/ /Volumes/HDDbackup
```

If one or both drives are external drives then you need to keep the external drives mounted when the user logs out. Keep in mind that macOS usually mounts external drives as `noowners` (set to ignore permission). You should consider enabling permissions on any external drive with the proper access for that user.

Then set the preference file-`/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/autodiskmount` :

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/autodiskmount AutomountDisksWithoutUserLogin -bool true
```

Note: I didn't test whether this preference file works in Sierra.